# Recovering checkboxes in python Tkinter

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I have a situation in which i create a few checkboxes and a 'save' button on a frame. Clicking on the button will save the current 'check status' of the checkboxes and close the frame (the frame has another frame as it's parent). The 'check status' is stored in a list in a separate .py file.

There's another button, clicking on which would i would want to restore those same check values on the check boxes. I am not sure what approach is proper here: whether to save the checkbox objects itself and load them or to create new checkboxes every time and apply the check status values on them.

This issue has taken up quite some time of mine as i am new to the python GUI concept, any help would be much appreciated.

P.S: if any details are required to make the question more clear kindly let me know.

EDIT: here's a small representation of what i have tried:

```
#file that generates the checkboxes (part of a bigger code)
var_list=[]    #list of the variables of the checkbox objects

load_status = savedata.load()   #fetch the saved status list from another file, if it exists

if len(load_status)!=0:   #if the checkboxes have already been created before
        for count in range(len(var_list)):
            if load_status[count] == 0:
                var_list[count].set(0)  #set/apply the values from the status list
            else:
                var_list[count].set(1)
        return



def check(var_list):
    check_status_list=[]
    for i in range(len(var_list)):
        c = var_list[i].get()
        check_status_list.append(c) #the status of the checkboxes that is stored in another file

var = IntVar()
var_list.append(var)
poll_check = ttk.Checkbutton(parent,variable=rr,command=lambda:check(var_list))
poll_check.place(x=x1,y=y1)
x1=x1+15
```

when i click on the save button the status list (check_status_list) is stored in another file. On clicking the third button ('load') i fetch the status list first and (try to) set the values on the already exsting checkbox objects.

Kindly feel free to point out the (obviously) silly mistake that this approach has.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have so far, and a clearer description of the problem than *"hasn't quite worked for me*"? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected behaviour (describe expected and actual behaviour)?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can't you just take your "save values" method and do a "restore values" method in the same fashion, setting the values from the list in the same order you stored them?

Comment: @tobias_k: I did use the same approach, i am even able to restore the values. But i am not sure how to use them (as in paste the values) on the checkbox objects.